# Why boxing reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, boxing

ECMA-335, 1.8.2.4, specifies that boxable types include reference types (excluding managed pointers/byrefs) and generic parameters.

What is the purpose of boxing reference types? Is the functionality and memory representation of a boxed reference object any different compare to the unboxed one?

Comment: .NET allows a reference type to be boxed, but C# does not.  The runtime allows it, but that functionality will never be leveraged by the C# compiler.

Comment: @Servy, how does that work in practice, though hypothetical I realize. Would it be like `var o = (object)myRefInstance;`? It's weird because `myRefInstance` clearly already bases `object`.

Comment: Also, "If typeTok is a reference type, the box instruction does  returns val unchanged as obj" - III.4.1.

Comment: @neoistheone That's valid C# code that doesn't involve boxing.  Note that it talks about boxing the actual reference type, not the reference pointing to it, so such a theoretical operation would actually perform a bitwise copy of the members of the instance of the object, not just copying the reference, as the code you showed would do.  It would act similar to how `MemberwiseClone` acts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing logically wrong with boxing a reference type reference.  It is just a no-op, nothing changes.

But Ecma-335 isn't always a good description for what is *really* implemented in the .NET CLR.  The JIT_Box() helper function that implements Opcodes.Box will actually throw an InvalidCastException when it is asked to box a value that's not a value type.  It expects a compiler and the jitter to know when to suppress the boxing conversion when it is unnecessary.  They do.

Comment: But it does accept a generic parameter that represents a reference type without throwing an exception. In that case the no-op behavior is required to support casting from `T` to `object`.

Comment: That's a valid point.  The jitter is already aware of T being a reference type and completely omits the code for the boxing conversion.

Comment: Did you check if it actually throws when using `box` on a normal reference type? Perhaps the JITter optimizes it out in that case as well before it reaches the exception throw code.

Comment: Yes, the jitter simply omits the call to JIT_Box for T's of a reference type.  The reference is already good as-is.

Comment: I meant the non generic case, since if it omitted the `JIT_Box` call in that case as well, the behaviour of the CLR would be consistent with the spec, and the `InvalidCastException` check would never trigger.

Comment: I don't know how to write code that tests that, other than writing IL.  Seems pointless, I know it throws from the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the generic function:

```
object MyBox<T>(T value)
{
    return (object)value;
}
```

This compiles to:

```
ldarg.1     
box         01 00 00 1B 
ret
```

The expected behavior of this function is a no-op if `T` is a reference type, boxing the value to itself.

Boxing a value that's know to be a reference type is less useful, but specifying it in a way that's consistent with generics is simple and consistent.